# Unable to open tor in Ubunutu Gnome 16.04

Tags: command-line, gnome, 16.04, ubuntu-gnome, tor

**I tried to installed tor from terminal by the following command**

```
 sudo apt-get install tor
```

Now i can't open Tor browser. I can't find it in my programs. I tried to open it using terminal.

**My command**:

```
tor
```

**And I see the following message**s:

```
May 28 14:01:06.679 [notice] Tor v0.2.7.6 (git-605ae665009853bd) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips and Zlib 1.2.8.
May 28 14:01:06.680 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
May 28 14:01:06.710 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
May 28 14:01:06.736 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
May 28 14:01:06.736 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
May 28 14:01:06.736 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
May 28 14:01:06.736 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Comment: Run `killall tor` then run `tor` again, it says it is already running.

Comment: Still the same problem


    May 29 17:26:03.423 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
    May 29 17:26:03.423 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
    May 29 17:26:03.423 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`tor` package is not Tor browser. It is a service to be used with various applications. It does not have GUI and can't be "found".

If you need to install Tor browser, run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```